# jQuery if cookie exists in array

Tags: javascript

I originally used the following jQuery statement to see if my cookie existed:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookie-foo') >= 0) {
    $("my-div").hide();
}
```

I now need to include multiple if statements, which I thought I'd tidy as an array:

```
var hidenfoo = ['cookie-foo', 'cookie-foo-two', 'cookie-foo-three'];
if (document.cookie.indexOf(hidenfoo) >= 0) {
    $("my-div").hide();
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I'm not getting any syntax errors, the statement simply doesn't resolve as true.

Comment: That array (even when implicitly converted to a string) is extremely unlikely to be part of your cookie string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test each array element separately, not the whole array. You can use the `some()` method to perform a test on each element and return true if any of them are true.

```
if (hidenfoo.some(cookie => document.cookie.includes(cookie))) {
    $("my-div").hide();
}
```